# Django - get message from websocket

Tags: django, websocket

I would like to be able to receive a message from the user

POST /createEvent

and immediately give it to all other users via websocket

/wsEvens

But it's not clear to me how to make interaction between these interfaces in Django

I use Django + DRF

Answer (score 0):

You can use Django Channels for this purpose [docs](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)

Comment: I know how to create a websocket. I do not understand how to transfer data to it from another interface. In flask I would just use a shared queue to pass the data